# How do I define a relabel_config in prometheus that provides a default value?

Tags: regex, prometheus

Say I have services that generally listen to port `8080`.  I'd like to do it so if I specify

```
prometheus.port=1234
```

It uses `1234` as the instance port but if I don't specify it, I would get `8080` as the value I would set on the label

I am presuming it's something along the lines of

```yaml
- source_labels: [__meta_dockerswarm_service_label_prometheus_port]
  regex: (\d+)
  target_label:  __port__
  replace: $1
  action: replace
```

Comment: Looks like a correct config, what is the problem with this? If you're unsure about the default value, the default port (the one that comes from service discovery) won't be replaced if the regex does not match.

Comment: but I actually don't have a default value set.  Unless... I have somewhere before it 
- source_labels [...] replace: 8080 that would set the value to be the default prior

Comment: Oh then you can add a preceding relabeling action, where you set the default value: `- {target_labels: "__port__", replacement: 8080}` (source labels and others are not mandatory yk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```yaml
- target_label:  __port__
  replacement: 8080
  action: replace

- source_labels: [__meta_dockerswarm_service_label_prometheus_port]
  regex: (\d+)
  target_label:  __port__
  replacement: $1
  action: replace
```

Then combined with the following to provide the port number for the service

```yaml
- source_labels: [ __meta_dockerswarm_service_name ]
  target_label: service
  action: replace
- source_labels: [ __address__ ]
  target_label: __address__
  regex: (.+):(\d+)
  replacement: $1
  action: replace
- source_labels: [ __address__, __port__ ]
  target_label: __address__
  regex: (.+);(\d+)
  replacement: $1:$2
  action: replace
```